# Complex Grouping in Sql with two or three Group criteria for single table and Joins

Tags: sql-server

This is my table in ms-sql 2008

```
Id  ReceiptNo   StudId  Year    SchoolId    ClassId FeeId   Paid    Balance
18  1             22    1        4           1       8       50      100
19  1             22    1        4           1       9      100     2300
20  2             23    1        5           1       9      200     2200
21  2             23    1        5           1      10      100      900
22  3             22    1        4           1       8      100        0
23  3             22    1        4           1       9      100     2200
```

I want rows where **Balance** is minimum but not 0, of that specific **StudId** and **FeeId**. Actually I want to show pending Fees to User, meaning, this Student has this much balance remaining of this fee type for this Academic Year. If you observe row with **Id 18** has **StudId 22** and **FeeId 8** and **Balance 100**, now row with **Id 22** shows **Balance 0** with same student and same fee, meaning this 22 student has paid all fees of **8 FeeId**,  so I don’t  want this student for **FeeId 8**. Now the same student has paid fee with **FeeId 9**, row with **Id 19 & 23** and has two **Balance 2300 and 2200**, so I want to show that **StudId 22** has **Balance** of 2200 remaining for **FeeId 9**, meaning I want to show row with **Id 23** and ***NOT*** the row with **Id 19**. Now this applies to all students for whatever Fee Id they have.

I have tried this but not getting

```
SELECT StudentId,FeeTypeId,MIN(FeesBalance) 
FROM FeesCollectionRS 
WHERE FeesBalance !=0 GROUP BY StudentId,FeeTypeId
```

Actually in reality my query will be some what like this

```
SELECT  f.StudentId,f.AcademicYear,f.SchoolId,f.MstClassId,f.FeeTypeId,d.PrnNo ,dbo.GetStudNameByStudid(f.StudentId) student, 
        CAST(year(a.StartOfYear)as CHAR(4))+'-'+ CAST(year(a.EndOfYear)as CHAR(4)) [Academic Year],c.Name,m.FeeType,f.FeesBalance 
FROM 
        FeesCollectionRS f JOIN AcademicYearMasterRS a 
        ON f.AcademicYear = a.Id JOIN ClassMasterRS c 
        ON f.MstClassId = c.MstClassId JOIN MstFeeType m 
        ON f.FeeTypeId = m.FeeTypeId JOIN MstStudentRS d 
        ON d.StudentId = f.StudentId 
WHERE   
        f.AcademicYear =1 and f.FeesBalance !=0
```

Comment: Could you post your expected result?

Comment: I have explained what I Expect, Last query with joins is for getting Student Names, Fee Names etc to show to users. I am not able to query with one table i.e. main table FEESCOLLECTIONRS so how can i show you my expected result, with multiple joins and groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af997/7)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentFees
(
  Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ReceiptNo INT,
  StudId INT,
  [Year] SMALLINT,
  SchoolId INT,
  ClassId INT,
  FeeId INT,
  Paid INT,
  Balance INT
)
INSERT INTO StudentFees
VALUES (18, 1, 22, 1, 4, 1, 8, 50, 100),
       (19, 1, 22, 1, 4, 1, 9, 100, 2300),
       (20, 2, 23, 1, 5, 1, 9, 200, 2200),
       (21, 2, 23, 1, 5, 1, 10, 100, 900),
       (22, 3, 22, 1, 4, 1, 8, 100, 0),
       (23, 3, 22, 1, 4, 1, 9, 100, 2200)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT StudId, FeeId, [Year], MAX(Id) As MaxId
  FROM StudentFees
  GROUP BY StudId, FeeId, [Year]
)
SELECT SF.StudId, SF.[Year],
       SF.SchoolId, SF.ClassId, SF.FeeId, SF.Balance
FROM StudentFees SF
INNER JOIN CTE
   ON CTE.MaxId = SF.Id
WHERE SF.Balance > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af997/7/0)**:

```
| StudId | Year | SchoolId | ClassId | FeeId | Balance |
|--------|------|----------|---------|-------|---------|
|     22 |    1 |        4 |       1 |     9 |    2200 |
|     23 |    1 |        5 |       1 |     9 |    2200 |
|     23 |    1 |        5 |       1 |    10 |     900 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HAVING` clause to filter out minimums that are zero:

```
SELECT StudentId, FeeTypeId, MIN(FeesBalance) MinFeesBalance
FROM FeesCollectionRS 
GROUP BY StudentId, FeeTypeId
HAVING MIN(FeesBalance) > 0
```

This first groups to find the minimum, then returns only those groups that have the criteria in `HAVING`, which is like a `WHERE` equivalent for groups and is applied to the result of aggregations rather than column values.